# Redirect all routes in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React/Redux app and if a user hasn't finished the signup process if they log in again I want them to be redirected to the signup route for the step they are on no matter what route they try to go to. What's the best way for me to do this without having to make a custom route for every single one of my routes with that logic inside? Here is my basic router:

```
render() {
  return (
   <Router history={history}>
     <Switch>
       <HomeRoute exact path="/" publicComp={Start} privateComp={Rooms}/>
       <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
       <Route path="/signup" component={SignUpMain}/>
    </Switch>
   </Router>
  );
}
```

Ideally, something where I can just say "on all of these routes if signup isn't complete redirect to /signup". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please add your react-router version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to replace your Route components with a higher order component that redirects to signup.

```
const RedirectRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
        <Redirect
          to="/signup"
        />
    }
  />
);
```

If you add the higher order components to the bottom of the file with your Router above then you can just replace the Route components like so...

```
render() {
  return (
   <Router history={history}>
     <Switch>
       <RedirectRoute exact path="/" render={() => <HomeRoute exact path="/" publicComp={Start} privateComp={Rooms}/>}/>
       <RedirectRoute path="/login" component={Login}/>
       <Route path="/signup" component={SignUpMain}/>
    </Switch>
   </Router>
  );
 }
```

If you want to keep the higher order component in a seperate file then just import it like you would any other component.

Comment: If higher order components are new to you, don't let them intimidate you. They are just components that can take another component as a prop. They are handy when you find yourself repeating things a lot like you would if you were to redirect each route individually. More in the docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: I already have a custom component <HomeRoute /> that has custom logic in it about redirecting. I am planning on having many more routes and custom routes like that, so need a way to have a higher level piece of logic that dictates all of those routes. In your solution, it looks like my <HomeRoute /> disappeared. Can I do a higher order component on top of my already higher ordered component of <HomeRoute />

Comment: Yeah, you can make a higher, higher order component in the same way. You pass it in like so...`<RedirectRoute exact path="/" render={() => <HomeRoute exact path="/" publicComp={Start} privateComp={Rooms}/>}/>`. I'll edit my response to include that.

Comment: That said, I side stepped this initially to avoid any possible confusion between using `component={}` and `render={() => # }` in the `Route` component because it doesn't matter. You are redirecting, so that component you pass in is irrelevant.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the difference is that that the render approach lets you pass props in with your component. Explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By7vJuSPaYo